# Use multiple versions of nlog

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, web-config, gac, nlog

I'm new to nlog, pardon my ignorance if I've missed something trivial.

I'm hosting several applications using IIS7, some use nlog 1.0.0.505 and some use NLog 2.0. I'm not sure how to create a web.config to accomodate both versions.

Is it possible to put several versions of the nlog.dll into the GAC so that each application has a list of versions to select from?

Is it perhaps a better idea to remove nlog from the GAC and let the application use the nlog it was deployed with? In that case, how do I reference nlog in web.config (to set targets etc)

Would greatly appreciate any help or pointers to where I can read more.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to create separate App Domains for each application or at least for each application that uses a different version of a dependent dll.  A single App Domain can't load multiple versions of the same dll.

Answer (score 1):

We ended up letting the application provide the nlog.dll file and did not specify version number in the global web.config.

Answer (score 0):

after some fighting... (if u dont want the story just copy the code below)

lets start by saying that the 1 of the reasons the GAC (Global Assymbly Cache) was invented was to use multiple versions of dll in the same place.

so..i have a Sharepoint project with NLog 2.0, where i need to add a 2nd solution with dll that depends on NLog 3.2, problem was, after pushing all to GAC (ans to SafeControls - for sp devs) was that the logger just never logged in the new solution.

the bell ringed when i looked again at my web.config

```
<section name="nlog" type="NLog.Config.ConfigSectionHandler, NLog, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5120e14c03d0593c" />
```

Notice the **Version=2.0.0.0**

so then i got that the NLog just loads the configuration for the old proj and somehow not passing it when starting to use the 3.2 dll.

I also trying Reloading the configuration, doing DeepCopy, cant understand why that didnt work.

then i re-defined a `LoggingConfiguration` in the code to re-init the logger while saving the old config, logged in that class, and then over-again in the Destructor to re-init with the old config.

I guess the result is that the logger is now using 3.2 everywhere with the 2.0 config.

but then i hated 2 things: 1 - having a destructor, 2 - not having the config from the web.config, and trying to do all that strait didnt work, and observing that there is some delay sometimes with the logs i figured that there is probably some queue or something i finnaly found the right way to make a CTOR that will know to re-init the NLog appropriately:

```
    public EncryptEventReceiver()
    {
        oldConfig = LogManager.Configuration;

        Task t = new Task(() =>
        {
            FileTarget target = new FileTarget();
            target.FileName = "c:\\Data\\Logs\\MyProj\\EncryptEventReceiver.txt";
            target.Layout = "${message}";
            target.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;

            LoggingRule rule = new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Trace, target);

            LoggingConfiguration config = new LoggingConfiguration();
            config.AddTarget("FileLog", target);
            config.LoggingRules.Add(rule);

            LogManager.Configuration = config;

            var _logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
            _logger.Trace("EncryptEventReceiver CTOR initialized Logger");
        });

        t.Start();
        t.Wait();

        LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger().Trace("EncryptEventReceiver MIDDLE");
        LogManager.Configuration = oldConfig;
        nlog3 = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
        nlog3.Trace("EncryptEventReceiver CTOR done, nlog3 ready");
    }
```

EDIT:
in the end that caused some logs to miss so i returned to CTOR-Destrucor, for a heavier use drinking the web-config is advised

```
    public static Logger nlog3;
    private static LoggingConfiguration oldConfig;

    public EncryptEventReceiver()
    {
        oldConfig = LogManager.Configuration;

        FileTarget target = new FileTarget();
        target.FileName = "c:\\Data\\Logs\\MyProj\\EncryptEventReceiver.txt";
        target.Layout = "${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd HH\\:mm\\:ss}   ${level}   ${message}   ${exception:format=tostring}";
        target.ArchiveAboveSize = 5242880;
        target.ArchiveFileName = "c:\\Data\\Logs\\MyProj\\Archive_EncryptEventReceiver\\EncryptEventReceiver_${shortdate}_{#}.txt";
        target.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;

        LoggingRule rule = new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Trace, target);

        LoggingConfiguration config = new LoggingConfiguration();
        config.AddTarget("FileLog", target);
        config.LoggingRules.Add(rule);

        LogManager.Configuration = config;

        nlog3 = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
        nlog3.Trace("EncryptEventReceiver CTOR done, nlog3 ready");
    }

    ~EncryptEventReceiver()
    {
        nlog3.Trace("EncryptEventReceiver Destructor");
        LogManager.Configuration = oldConfig;
        LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger().Trace("EncryptEventReceiver Destructor done");
    }
```